# Trying to write a get request on nestjs to search by the name of the task

Tags: node.js, search, nestjs

I'm trying to write a get request on nestjs to search by the name.

```
@Controller('tasks') //Decorator tasks
export class TasksController {
  constructor(private readonly tasksService: TasksService) {} //injecte. Delegate our service from ./tasks.service

  @Post()
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED) //Catched error and output number error. CREATED it error 201
  @Header('Cache-Control', 'none') //Adds Header
  create(@Body() createTasks: CreateTasksDto): Promise<Task> {
    return this.tasksService.create(createTasks);
  }

  @Get()
  getAll() {
    return this.tasksService.getAll(), console.log('Work');
  }

  // @Get()
  // // @Redirect('https://youtube.com', 301) //Redirect in case of an error 301
  // getAll() {
  //   return 'getAll'
  // }

  @Get(':id')  // Get dynamic param id from Request Route Parameters
  getOne(@Param('id') id: ObjectId) {
    return this.tasksService.getOne(id);
  }

  @Delete(':id')  // Get dynamic param id from Request Route Parameters
  remove(@Param('id') id: ObjectId) {
    return this.tasksService.remove(id);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  update(@Body() updateTask: UpdateTasksDto, @Param('id') id: string) {
    // For update we creat separately update DTO ./dto/update-tasks.dto
    return this.tasksService.update(updateTask, id);
  }

  @Get('search')
  search(@Query('query') query: string): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksService.search(query);
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Task.name) private taskModel: Model<TaskDocument>) {}

  async getAll(): Promise<Task[]> {
    const tasks = await this.taskModel.find();
    return tasks;
  }

  async getOne(id: ObjectId) {
    const task = await this.taskModel.findById(id);
    return task;
  }

  async create(tasksDto: CreateTasksDto): Promise<Task> {
    const newTask = await this.taskModel.create(tasksDto);
    return newTask;
  }

  async remove(id: ObjectId) {
    const task = await this.taskModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return task;
  }

  async update(updateTask: UpdateTasksDto, id: string) {
    return this.taskModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateTask);
  }

  async search(query): Promise<Task[]> {
    const tasks = await this.taskModel.find({
      task: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') },
    });
    return tasks;
  }
}
```

I can't understand why I get the error
"ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Accessing
the object failed for the value "search" (type string) on the path "_id" for
the "Task" model
Caster error: casting to ObjectId failed
for the value "search" (type string) along the path "_id" for the "Task" model"

In Postman, it outputs error 500 on a GET request for links
http://localhost:3000/tasks/search
http://localhost:3000/search

Comment: Could you add the whole controller class to see what would be the correct path to make the request

Comment: Added all the Controller and Service code )

Comment: The rest of the queries work fine

Answer (score 0):

The order matters when you're declaring your routes.

Endpoint:

```js
@Get('search')
search(@Query('query') query: string): Promise<Task[]> {
  return this.tasksService.search(query);
}
```

Should be declared before:

```js
@Get(':id')  // Get dynamic param id from Request Route Parameters
getOne(@Param('id') id: ObjectId) {
  return this.tasksService.getOne(id);
}
```

Otherwise `getOne` Handles the request